# Assigning reference to a variable in C++

Tags: c++, reference

My question is why it is possible to assign reference to a variable that is not declared as reference?

Thank you.

```
int &testRef(int &x)
{
    return ++x;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 1, y;
    y = testRef(x); // assigning testRef(x) which is int& to y which is int
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is possible because it makes sense. Life would be very difficult if one couldn't construct objects from references. The assignment means "assign the value of the object the reference refers to (`x`) to the LHS (`y`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`y = testRef(x);` will take a *value copy* of the reference returned by `testRef`. That can be useful if you want to make subsequent modifications to the return value.

If `testRef` were to return a `const` reference, then you'd have no choice but to take a value copy if you wanted to change the return value. That helps in achieving program stability.

Comment: Why is it so? And where can I found more information about it?

Comment: Excuse me for "reviving" this post after so long, but what would happen if it was something like this:

`auto& y = testRef(x); `

Thank you.

Comment: @Envy Then no value copy is taken. `y` is an `int&`.

Comment: @Bathsheba so any modifications I make to `y` will affect the reference returned by `testRef` right? If y wasn't an `int&`, its changes would not affect the returned reference, right?

Answer (score 3):

Think of a reference as an **alias**, just a name of something. You're not assigning the reference. You're assigning the something that the reference names (or rather, that it references).

Answer (score 2):

When passing by reference, actually nothing new is created, only an **alias** of original object being passed is created that points to the same object.
Literally, the 'x' parameter in the function() and the x being passed originally are the same.

By the way

```
int &testRef(int &x)
{
    return ++x;
}
```

returning by **reference** makes it possible to assign rvalue : something like

```
int main()
{
    int x = 1, y;
    y = testRef(x); 
     testRef(y) = 5;  //by doing this you are assigning y as 5 
    std::cout<<y;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is indeed a very complicated example.

Comment: @DieselDL, actually you can find in c++ documentation when learning about function calls (pass by reference, return by reference)
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/